# NSMutableArray of NSMutableArrays, addObject problem

Tags: objective-c, ios, singleton, nsmutablearray

I'm relatively new to objective-C and I'm having a problem with a 2D NSMutableArray and it's behaviour when adding the contents of one NSMutableArray to another.

I have a singleton class containing an NSMutableArray. This array is for storing NSURL values.
At a certain point in my program, I need to add this NSMutableArray as a whole to another NSMutableArray.

I do something like this:
[arrayIWantStuffIn addObject: mySingleton.singletonMutableArray];

The problem I have is that I need to reset my singltonMutableArray to start storing a new set of NSURL values.  The addObject function above appears to be passing by reference rather than passing by value, so when I do:

[mySingleton.singletonMutableArray removeAllObjects];

The data stored in arrayIWantStuffIn is wiped as well.

How can I achieve a 'deep' addObject that is adding a NSMutableArray to another NSMutableArray by value and not by reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont actually need a deep copy just another mutableCopy. This can be done simply by doing the following

```
[arrayIWantStuffIn addObject: [[mySingleton.singletonMutableArray mutablCopy] autorelease]];
```

Once that is done when the singletonMutableArray is cleared or changed it will not change your items in arrayIWantStuffIn and you can still modify the contents independently.

Comment: That worked like a charm.  Thanks Joe.  Just the make sure I'm understanding this correctly, the [mySingleton.singletonMutableArray mutableCopy] makes a deep copy of my singletonMutableArray and then uses that copy as the object passed to addObject?

Comment: It will not make a deep copy of your `singletonMutableArray` so the mutableCopy will still point to the same `NSURL`'s at the time of the copy but when you make changes to `singletonMutableArray` it will not change your `arrayIWantStuffIn` and vice versa. Also `NSURL`'s are immutable so you do not have to worry about those changing.